# Number of sets $S$ for which number of permutations in $S_n$ with descent set $S$ is odd

Tags: co.combinatorics, permutations, enumerative-combinatorics

The *descent set* $D(w)$ of a permutation $w=a_1 a_2\cdots a_n\in\frak{S}_n$ is
defined by $D(w)=\{ 1\leq i\leq n-1\,:\, a_i>a_{i+1}\}$.

Given a set $S$, let
$\beta_n(S)$ denote the number of permutations $w\in\frak{S}_n$ with
$D(w)=S$, and let $f(n)$ be the number of subsets $S$ of
$\{1,2,\dots,n-1\}$ for which $\beta_n(S)$ is odd.

> **QUESTION.** Is there a nice
> formula, recurrence, etc., for $f(n)$? The values of $f(n)$ for $1\leq
> n\leq 15$ are (up to some glitch in my Maple code)
> $$ 1,2,2,8,8,16,32,128,128,256,512,1024,2048,4096,7424. $$

**Note.** A closely related problem is to look at permutations $w\in
  \frak{S}_n$ whose descent set is *contained* in $S$. Let $\alpha_n(S)$
denote the number of such permutations (which is equal to a simple
multinomial coefficient). Let $g(n)$ be the number of subsets $S$ of
$\{1,2,\dots,n-1\}$ for which $\alpha_n(S)$ is odd. It is not hard
to show that $g(n)$ is equal to the number of ordered set partitions
of $\{1,2,\dots,b(n)\}$, where $b(n)$ is the number of 1's in the binary expansion of $n$. See https://oeis.org/A000670 for further
information on ordered set partitions.

Comment: The paper "Cyclotomic factors of the descent set polynomial" by
Denis Chebikin, Richard Ehrenborg,  Pavlo Pylyavskyy, and Margaret Readdy, J. Combin. Theory Ser. A. 116 (2009), 247–264, https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0097316508000897
may be relevant. They consider the number of odd values of $\beta_n(S)$.

Comment: Thanks for this reference (which at one time I was aware of). According to their results, it suffices to find $f(n)$ for $n=2^k-1$.

Comment: @RichardStanley: I don't have a Maple code written, how confident are your about $7424$.

Comment: I can confirm 7424.

Comment: According to the paper in Ira Gessel's link, $f(31)=2^{17}\cdot 13\cdot 307$.

Comment: Does it seem true that $f(n)=2^{n-2}$ unless $n=2^k$ or $n=2^k-1$?

Comment: @T.Amdeberhan, no. That holds for $n$ having a Hamming weight of 2 or 3. See the paper referenced above, table 1.

Comment: I confirm $f(31) = 2^{17} \cdot 3 \cdot 307$ with the breakdown by size of $S$ having g.f. $q^{30} + 285q^{28} + 1980q^{27} + 14215q^{26} + 71760q^{25} + 291715q^{24} + 971640q^{23} + 2742385q^{22} + 6685520q^{21} + 14204349q^{20} + 26215940q^{19} + 42026655q^{18} + 58640480q^{17} + 71505675q^{16} + 76363152q^{15} + 71505675q^{14} + 58640480q^{13} + 42026655q^{12} + 26215940q^{11} + 14204349q^{10} + 6685520q^{9} + 2742385q^{8} + 971640q^{7} + 291715q^{6} + 71760q^{5} + 14215q^{4} + 1980q^{3} + 285q^{2} + 1$. [Code and more data](https://gist.github.com/pjt33/9a2b901bdf618272c4a4c76bf81d356e).

Comment: I get $f(63) = 2^{36} \cdot 11 \cdot 1031 \cdot 2939$, thus the ratio $f(n) / 2^{n - 1}$ for any number with Hamming weight $6$ is $11 \cdot 1031 \cdot 2939 / 2^{26} \sim 0.49734$.

Comment: $1/2 - \rho(63) = 7 \cdot 11 \cdot 13 \cdot 223 / 2^{26}$. I wonder if that qualifies as "factors so nicely" (see Section 9) according to reference authors...

Comment: @PeterTaylor: did you mean 13 instead of 3 as a factor?

Comment: Yes, apologies for the typo.

Comment: Via MacMahon's formula and Kummer's theorem for multinomials, $f(2^k-1)$ is also the number of sublattices of the Boolean lattice of order $2^k$ which have an odd number of paths from $\emptyset$ to $[k]$. However, I've thought about this for a few days and not found a way of using it to bring $f(127)$ into reach.