# Generating function for "descents" and "cycle-types", in tandem

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, permutations, enumerative-combinatorics

This question is inspired but not directly related to this recent [Stanley's MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/419698/number-of-sets-s-for-which-number-of-permutations-in-s-n-with-descent-set-s).

The *descent set* $D(w)$ of a permutation $w=a_1 a_2\cdots a_n\in\frak{S}_n$ (the symmetric group on $\{1,\dots,n\}$) is
defined by $D(w)=\{ 1\leq i\leq n-1\,:\, a_i>a_{i+1}\}$. Denote the cardinality of $D(w)$ by $des(w)$.

The [Eulerian polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_number) are known to express
$$A_n(x)=\sum_{w\in\frak{S}_n}x^{des(w)}$$
whose exponential generating function is given by
$$\sum_{n\geq0}A_n(x)\,\frac{z^n}{n!}=\frac{1-z}{z-e^{(1-z)x}}.$$
Suppose we wish to refine this by including the *cycle-type* of each permutation.

> **QUESTION.** Is there a generating function for the sum
> $$\sum_{w\in\frak{S}_n}x^{des(w)}\,t_1^{a_1}t_2^{a_2}\cdots t_n^{a_n}$$
> where $(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ is the cycle-type of $w$? **Caveat.** the $a_i$'s are non-negative integers.

**Examples.** The first few polynomials for $n=1, 2, 3$ and $4$:
\begin{align*} &t_1 \\ &t_1^2+t_2x \\ &t_1^3+(2t_1t_2+2t_3)x+t_1t_2x^2 \\
&t_1^4+(3t_1^2t_2+4t_1t_3+t_2^2+3t_4)x+(3t_1^2t_2+4t_1t_3+t_2^2+3t_4)x^2+t_2^2x^3.
\end{align*}

Comment: Close to what you want: the number of permutations with descent set $S\subseteq [n-1]$ and cycle type $\lambda$ is $\langle L_{\lambda}, s_{B_S}\rangle$ where $s_{B_S}$ is the ribbon Schur function and $L_{\lambda}$ is the Lyndon symmetric function. See Stanley's recent slides: https://math.mit.edu/~rstan/transparencies/permenum.pdf.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Counting permutations by cycle type and descents was first accomplished in I. Gessel and C. Reutenauer, *Counting permutations with given cycle structure and
descent set*, J. Combin. Theory Ser. A 64, No. 2 (1993), 189–215.

Using the results of this paper, an explicit (though somewhat complicated) formula for the generating function asked for can be found in
Jason Fulman, *The distribution of descents in fixed conjugacy classes of the symmetric groups*, J. Combin. Theory Ser. A 84 (1998), no. 2, 171–180. Another proof of Fulman's formula is Theorem 7.1 (c) in
Ira M. Gessel and Yan Zhuang,
*Plethystic formulas for permutation enumeration,*
Adv. Math. 375 (2020), 107370, 55 pp.

Comment: Thank you for this, Ira.